# openvz маппинг каталога хоста

Tags: openvz

OpenVZ7, 3.10.0-862.11.6.vz7.64.7

Нужно в контейнер передать каталог с хоста, к которому смонтирован iscsi диск.
В Openvz6, это делалось легко. Здесь, мне ругается, что не понимает simfs. Поменял в vz.conf - VEFSTYPE с ext4 на simfs, но ошибка та же.

Answer (score 0):

разобрался

```
mount --bind /backup/ /vz/root/1100/backup
```